# Mongodb less than condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to fetch all documents greater than or equal to one date and less than or equal to another. The less than condtion is not being considered in the result. There is something wrong with my query. MongoDB Version 3.2

```
db.flight_itinerary.aggregate( [ { $match: {  created_at: { $lte: new ISODate("2019-11-02") }  ,  created_at: { $gte: new ISODate("2019-11-01") }  ,  "status" : "BOOKING_SUCCESSFULL"}} ,  { $group:{_id: { created_at:"$created_at"}, count: { $sum: 1 } ,total_amount:{$sum:"$payment.Amount"}}}] ).pretty();
```

The output has documents like this too

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "created_at" : ISODate("2019-12-01T09:01:56Z")
    },
    "count" : 1,
    "total_amount" : 10585
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to either of the following versions:

Option 1:

```
{
    $match: {
        created_at: {$lte: new ISODate("2019-11-02") ,$gte: new ISODate("2019-11-01") }
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
{
    $match: {
        $and: [
            {created_at: {$lte: new ISODate("2019-11-02") }},
            {created_at: {$gte: new ISODate("2019-11-01")},
        ]
    }
}
```

The current way you have your query written leads to unstable results.